# Unable to process AJAX request, getting 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, http-status-code-404, ruby-on-rails-2

I am using rails 2.3.18 and I am calling a controller method via ajax from a partial page. My controller name where the target method resides is ReportsController. I just want to print the params in this controller method, submitted via ajax.

Here is my ajax code:

```
$( ".accordion" ).click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      url: '/admin/reports/bonus_details',
      data: { "article": { "title": "acme", "text": "text of the article" } },
      });

    return false;
});
```

I have made changes in my routes.rb file accordingly. And I can see the request is being processed in development.log as follows:-

```
Jan 16 11:55:15 bit rails[4203]: Processing Admin::ReportsController#bonus_details (for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-01-16 11:55:15) [GET]
Jan 16 11:55:15 bit rails[4203]: Parameters: {"article"=>{"title"=>"acme", "text"=>"text of the article"}}
```

But in the web console I am getting the following error:

```
jquery.js?1515753387:7845 GET http://localhost:3000/admin/reports/bonus_details?article%5Btitle%5D=acme&article%5Btext%5D=text+of+the+article 404 (Not Found)
```

And my controller method also not get executed. Here is my target controller method:

```
def bonus_details
  p params

  respond_to do |format|
   format.json
  end
end
```

Please help me to figure out this. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: @abhrasdip lets try the solution given below and let me know for further guidance

Comment: show your routes